# skipping a filled cell that was input manually by the automated apps script

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm relatively new to google apps Script coding but I have taken the Javascript learning on Khan and i need some assistance with a problem I'm trying to figure out in google spreadsheets.

The problem is that I am trying to automate information from one sheet to the other like a copy so if an assistance inputs info the manager when he pulls out sheets, it will automatically have the info loaded. I have that part the part I need is if the manager puts in a piece of info I don't want the assistances info to overlap it.

I am pretty sure I need an if statement but not sure how to correctly word it in Apps Script.
This is what I have so far:

```
    function onOpen(e){
    /*SpreadsheetApp.getUi()*/
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var ss = sheet.getSheetByName('names');
    var range = ss.getRange('B2:B100');
    var data = range.getValues();
    var sheet1= SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var ds = sheet1.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    ds.getRange(2,2, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);

    var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sss = sheet2.getSheetByName('names');
    var range2 = sss.getRange('C2:C100');
    var data2 = range2.getValues();
    var sheet3= SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var ds1 = sheet3.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    ds1.getRange(2,1, data2.length, data2[0].length).setValues(data2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always get the data of the cell then add the updated value so that the data will not overlap.

Sheet 1

```
A B C

1 Name  Work  Budget

2 John  Guard 180
3 Kevin Prog. 200
```

Use `getValue()` of the first sheet, then get the value of the update.Use the variable of the first data and concatenate it with the update to avoid overlapping info.

```
var range = sheet.getRange("A2");
var data = range.getValue()
range.setValue(data+" Corrs")
```

## Update

Sheet 2

```
A B C

1 Name       Work  Budget

2 John Corss Guard 180
3 Kevin      Prog. 200
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: what does the "Corrs" do? and also would it work for entire columns that had information added to them like if on sheet 2 I input info would it help put it on sheet 1, then if i put info on sheet 1 would the info on sheet 2 overlaps it or be pushed below to prevent it.

Comment: "Corrs" would be the example for the update data. It would depend now on how you handle updates/edits on sheets1 and sheet2. You could create a [Class Protection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection), to  prohibit anyone other than the editor to update the data from sheet1 when the editor is updating sheet2 (vice versa). You might want to check [Control protected ranges and sheets in Google Sheets with Apps Script](https://developers.googleblog.com/2015/02/control-protected-ranges-and-sheets-in.html) for more info about control Protect ranges/sheets.